# conditional read from second file bash

Tags: bash

I'm struggling with how to hand the stdout/stdin from within a loop when that while loop already reads from stdin.

I've tried using a different file descriptor for the main loop but I'm getting very strange results in the echo coming out for the second set of vars (blank or odd data).

eg:

```
grep something /tmp/from_some_file > /tmp/abc123
while IFS="," read -u 3  var1 var2 var3
do
  if [ $var1 = "abc" ] ; then
     flag=true
  fi
  grep var1 /tmp/second_file | read sec1 sec2 sec3
  echo "$var1/$var2/$var3  $sec1 : $sec2 : $sec3"
done  3< /tmp/abc123
```

For the purposes here I've shortened all of the if checks I'm running and simplified the names/files etc.   But this is the basic check.. The values in sec1,sec2,sec3 are coming out either blank or strange values.

Originally I didn't have the <3 redirect, same result,  I also just used to pull in the whole line to one variable and append it to the output, but now I need to separate the CSV file up into vars so I can run conditional checks on the values.

So - how can I get two reads running at the same time within the loop ?

When I set -x on I can see the grep is working, I get the CSV line out that I'd expect, but they don't load up into sec1/2/3

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the second `read` is run in a subshell, as are all commands run in pipelines, eg. `a=0; a=1 | a=2 | a=3; echo $a` will print `0`.

The `grep ... | read sec1 sec2 sec3` really sets those variables, but only in the separate process the `read` command is run in.

The simplest way in `bash`/`ksh`/`zsh` is to use [process substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution):

```
read sec1 sec2 sec3 < <(grep var1 /tmp/second_file)
```

Notice the space between the two `<`.

You can do the same with the main loop `while ...; do ... ; done < <(...)`.

Comment: Ah you star ! thankyou!  In one test I had been trying something similar but I'd used < $(cmd) instead thinking it had to be a subprocess.!

Comment: Do you know if this differs in RHEL7 ?  I have it working in RHEL6 but RHEL7 is spitting out syntax errors I'm working through.

Comment: I don't think there should be any difference. Please post an example.

Comment: Thanks I was able to work it out.. I'd forgotten the #!/bin/bash at the start of the script so when I moved the script to the final host it fell over as my default is bash.  For some reason that one line was the only out of the 500 lines in the script that failed!